# Create 2nd Page in a PDF Document

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-studio

I have written an android app to do inspections. It collects the data and then formats it and places it on a PDF document. I am having a problem creating a 2nd page of the PDF before I save it and email it. I have commented out "PAGE 2 OF PDF". This section of code up to the declaration of pdfName is where the problem is. I do not want to use anything like iText or Apose. Can anyone help???

```
public void createPDF(){

// Create a object of PdfDocument
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// content view is TableLayout of data
    View content = findViewById(id.final_table_layout_for_pdf_page_1);

// create a page info with attributes as below
// page number, height and width
// i have used height and width to that of pdf content view
    int pageNumber = 1;
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new     PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(content.getWidth(),
            content.getHeight() - 20, pageNumber).create();

// create a new page from the PageInfo
    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

// repaint the user's text into the page
    content.draw(page.getCanvas());

    // do final processing of the page
    document.finishPage(page);

/* PAGE 2 OF PDF

    content = findViewById(id.final_table_layout_for_pdf_page_2);

// create a page info with attributes as below
// for 2nd page
// i have used height and width to that of pdf content view
    pageNumber = 2;
    pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(content.getWidth(),
            content.getHeight() - 20, pageNumber).create();

// create a new page from the PageInfo
    page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

// repaint the user's text into the page
    content.draw(page.getCanvas());

// do final processing of the page
    document.finishPage(page);*/

// saving pdf document to root dir
    String pdfName = "pdf_inspection_demo.pdf";

// all created files will be saved at path /sdcard/PDFDemo_AndroidSRC/
    File outputFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/", pdfName);

    try {
        outputFile.createNewFile();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        document.writeTo(out);
        document.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorString = e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am having a problem creating a 2nd page of the PDF before I save it and email it" -- what, **precisely**, is the problem? "This section of code up to the declaration of pdfName is where the problem is" -- what, **precisely**, is the problem? Also, please do not hardcode paths (in particular, I would expect yours to be wrong on many devices). Use appropriate methods on `Context` or `Environment` to get at root directories for your use in constructing paths.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the path. I did this simply to ensure ease of access to the created file. The precise problem is when I create the 2nd page, the app stops. the LogCat doesn't really tell me anything as it throws a bunch of errors. Any thoughts as to why the commented out portion of the code would not work???

Answer (score 0):

```
private void generatePDF() {
   PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

    criNewPag(1,"ان شاء الله ",pdfDocument);
    criNewPag(2,"ان شاء الله ربي  ",pdfDocument);

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "GFG.pdf");
    try {
        pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PDF file generated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pdfDocument.close();


}
private void criNewPag(int numpag,String text, PdfDocument pdfDocument ){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Paint title = new Paint();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo mypageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pagewidth, pageHeight, numpag).create();
    PdfDocument.Page   myPage = pdfDocument.startPage(mypageInfo);
    Canvas canvas = myPage.getCanvas();
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gfgimage);
    scaledbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 140, 140, false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp, 56, 40, paint);
    title.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL));
    title.setTextSize(15);
    title.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_200));
    canvas.drawText("A portal for IT professionals.", 209, 100, title);
    canvas.drawText("Geeks for Geeks", 209, 80, title);
    title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
    title.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_200));
    title.setTextSize(15);
    title.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(text, 150, 240, title);

    pdfDocument.finishPage(myPage);
}
```

Comment: Any ideas how to automatically create next page if the current page is full of text?